# Finding and Highlighting Text in Dreamweaver Code View

Tags: javascript, html, api, dom, dreamweaver

I'm working on an extension and I would like to add some functionality so that I can search for a chunk of code and highlight it so that I can then call collapseSelectedCodeFragment on it and automatically collapse said code (just to keep everything organized).

However, I'm not sure how to go about finding and highlighting the code chunk in the code viewer.

Comment: I'm attempting to use the findNext API to select the text I want, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

    dreamweaver.setUpFind({searchString: 'testingthy', searchWhat: document, searchSource: true});dreamweaver.findNext(false, dom, true);
  dom.collapseSelectedCodeFragment(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing this for anyone wondering:

```
dreamweaver.setUpFind({searchString: newString, searchWhat: "document",  searchSource: true});
dreamweaver.canFindNext(true);
dreamweaver.findNext();
dom.collapseSelectedCodeFragment(false);
```